# node js html file loading problem , how can ı solve?

Tags: node.js, express

naber.html is loading but  kutu html isnot loading ,how to loading this two html files ?

> include 'naber.html' ,  include 'kutu.html'       how do i do like php

```
 var express=require("express")
    const as=express();
    const yol=require("path")
    var baska=require("./baska")
    as.get("/",(req,res)=>{
        res.sendfile(yol.join(__dirname+"/naber.html"))
        res.sendfile(yol.join(__dirname+"/kutu.html"))

    }).listen(5000)
```

Comment: Do you use a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use res.sendfile to send multiple files.

And why do you need to send 2 html file ?

Maybe make 2 routes to access the wanted file like :

```
var express=require("express")
const app=express();
const yol=require("path")
var baska=require("./baska")

app.get("/naber",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendfile(yol.join(__dirname+"/naber.html"))
})

app.get("/kutu",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendfile(yol.join(__dirname+"/kutu.html"))
})

app.listen(5000)
```

Comment: include 'naber.php' , include  'kutu.php'    like php